# Create a column with avg loss per day value in last row of the column-pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Day         water level         Avg loss per day
1               100                 NaN
2                90                 NaN
3                88                 NaN
4                87                 NaN
5                77                 NaN
6                75                 NaN
7                74                 (100-74)/7
```

I want to find the average water level loss per day in the third column of this dataframe.

Only the last row should have value and the rest 6 rows above should have NAN.

I tried using `.iloc` and `np.nan`.

```
                df['Avg loss per day']=(df['water level'].iloc[0]-df['water level'].iloc[6])/7
                df = df.round({'Avg loss per day': 2})
                df.loc[0:6,['Avg loss per day']]=np.nan
```

but its throwing error.
Is there any other way to do it without using iloc

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
df['Avg loss per day'] = df['water level'].shift(6).sub(df['water level']).div(7)
```

Or, if "Avg loss per day" is initially non-existent or empty:

```
df.loc[df.index[-1],
       'Avg loss per day'] = (df['water level'].iloc[0]
                             -df['water level'].iloc[-1])/7
```

Output:

```
   Day  water level Avg loss per day
0    1          100              NaN
1    2           90              NaN
2    3           88              NaN
3    4           87              NaN
4    5           77              NaN
5    6           75              NaN
6    7           74         3.714286
```